# How to show numbers(1,2,3) when clicked or tapped image in both android and ios xamarin forms

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, numbers

How to get genearate id while clicked that place to show number in image like(1,2,3,4) UI level is there any chance to achieve in both and Android and ios in xamarin or renderer. Thanks Advance

I am using Sfimageditor when I clicked particular position tap am getting x and y position based on I have to show the numbers on that posotion

### Xaml code

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <local:CustomImage x:Name="Img" TapEvent="Img_TapEvent"  Source="{Binding PhotoSource}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit">
                <local:CustomImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ImageTapCommand}" />
                </local:CustomImage.GestureRecognizers>
            </local:CustomImage>
        </StackLayout>
```

When clicked PhotoSource and save to generate id shows in UI level in image

Android Customimagerendeer:

```
 public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            float Xaxis = e.GetX();
            flaot Yaxis = e.GetY();
            return false;
        }
```

Ios Customimagerendeer:

```
public void TapHandler(UITapGestureRecognizer tgr)
        {
            CGPoint touchPoint = tgr.LocationInView(nativeElement);
            formsElement.OnTapEvent(float Xaxis = (float)touchPoint.X, float Yaxis = (float)touchPoint.Y);
        }
```

Comment: Am using CustomImagerender how can i achieve to generate id and view UI level in both android and ios

Comment: What do you mean with UI level?

Comment: @JuanSturla please see this screen shot (eg when I click the rectagle boxes and saved its show 1,2 based on x and y coordinated) in the image

Answer (score 0):

You can use relativelayout to set controls over picture, it has

> XConstraint, of type Constraint, which is an attached property that
> represents the constraint on the X position of the child.

> YConstraint, of type Constraint, which is an attached property that represents the
> constraint on the Y position of the child.

here is an example:

**Xaml:**

```
               <RelativeLayout x:Name="rel">
            <StackLayout>
              <Image Source="mypic.jpg" x:Name="pic">
                  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="on_Tapped"/>
                  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
              </Image>
                </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

**codebehind:**

```
  private void on_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rel.Children.Add(new Label
            {Text="1",
            TextColor=Color.Red

            }, () => new Rectangle(0, 10, 20, 20));//here is where you want to add the label
           
        }
```

For more information about it,

you can refer to this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout

Comment: Thanks. We need to add label text (1,2,3,4) based on the image X and Y axis. I have taken X and Y axis from the image using below reference link.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50318e68-4e06-4d08-8d2d-d839f720d006/how-do-i-put-points-on-image-and-get-coordinates-of-those-points-?forum=xamarinforms 

Do we need to do any calculations to do set LayoutBounds? Please suggest

Comment: If you want set the layout, use code like  " absoluteLayout.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = "Stylish Header",
            FontSize = 24
        }, new Point(30,25)); "

Comment: Please check the below link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552007/how-to-set-absoluteposition-on-my-image-using-absolutelayout-in-xamarin-forms?noredirect=1#comment122941223_69552007

Comment: try tapgetsure then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap

Comment: How to place inside text in image based on x and y position

Comment: check the update

Comment: image appear top left and shows small and text position in wrong place based on the image X and Y axis

Comment: .... then use absolutelayout, set the x,y in new Rectangle();

Comment: Also tried absolutelayout it works based on screen position not image position

Comment: the x y you get is based on screen and you want to set based on image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69611203/in-android-we-have-pixels-to-dp-and-dp-to-pixels-and-how-to-achieve-in-ios-xamar pls check that link. Thanks advance

Comment: I am checking it