# How to set AbsolutePosition on my image using AbsoluteLayout in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, position, absolutelayout

TouchAction event triggered overall entrire position of view, but in my case it triggered only in image area using AbsoluteLayout? But now it covered overall entire position of the view. how to achieve to only image position area

### xaml code

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="myabs"  >
            <local:CustomImage Source="{Binding PhotoSource}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"Aspect="AspectFit"/>
            <views:SKCanvasView
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"

            x:Name="canvasView" >
                <views:SKCanvasView.Effects>
                    <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True" TouchAction="TouchEffect_TouchAction" />
                </views:SKCanvasView.Effects>
            </views:SKCanvasView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

### Xaml.cs

```
private void TouchEffect_TouchAction(object sender, TouchTracking.TouchActionEventArgs args)
        {
            var x = args.Location.X;
            var y = args.Location.Y;
            var v = new View1();
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(v, new Rectangle(x, y, 0.25, 0.25));
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(v, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.SizeProportional);

            myabs.Children.Add(v);
        }
```

it covers the entire screen area in my scenario only triggered when I click image only

Comment: @JuanSturla edited and added above SkCanvasView covered entire screen how to set image area using AbsoluteLayout

Comment: @JuanSturla, Thanks for your reply. In SkCanvasView how to cover image part only

Comment: OH, so now it's working in the entire screen but you want only to work INSIDE the image? I got it backwards. Sorry about that.

Comment: @JuanSturla yes

Comment: Can't you just add that effect on your `CustomImage`?

Comment: @JuanSturla I don't know how to do that if any sample is there?

Comment: Something like you have in the XAML: `<local:CustomImage Source="{Binding PhotoSource}" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                <local:CustomImage.Effects>
                    <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True" TouchAction="TouchEffect_TouchAction" />
                </local:CustomImage>`

Comment: This will depend on the implementation of your `tt:TouchEffect`

Comment: @JuanSturla will  check and let you know

Comment: @JuanSturla am using customeffects and also remove in <local:CustomImage in AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" image appear small and top postion

Comment: Do not delete the LayoutBounds and Flags, I did that just to keep the comment simple

Comment: @JuanSturla yes checking both scenario removed and not removed 1. if I removed it shows small and top position 2. if I not delete it covers entire screen till same issue occur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238095/discussion-between-juan-sturla-and-newxamarin).